# Does a parameter passed by const reference fully acts as a variable of const type in a function?

Tags: c++, dictionary, key, constants, pass-by-reference

More precisely, I was wondering how many `std::pair` template constructor calls are made in the following code snippet: one (for a `std::pair<const KeyType, ValueType>`) or two (first one for a `std::pair<KeyType, ValueType>` by `make_pair` and then a second to `std::pair<const KeyType, ValueType>` by `insert`) ?

```
std::map<KeyType, ValueType> m;

void addToMap(const KeyType& key)
{
    ValueType val = someCalculation(key);
    m.insert(std::make_pair(key, val));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Two copies are made, as `std::make_pair(key,val)` returns a `std::pair<KeyType, ValueType>` rather than `std::pair<const KeyType, ValueType>`, so needs to be copied.

You *could* force `std::make_pair` to give the right type:

```
m.insert(std::make_pair<const KeyType, ValueType>(key, val));
```

But then you just may as well construct a `std::pair` directly:

```
m.insert(std::pair<const KeyType, ValueType>{key, val});
m.insert(decltype(m)::value_type(key,val));
```

However, the best option is to avoid creating a temporary `std::pair` in the first place by using `emplace`:

```
m.emplace(key, val);
```